# url rewrite module rule for page rewrite in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, web-config, url-rewrite-module

I am trying to use Microsoft Url Rewrite in one application I am working on and for testing purposes for example I have this url: `http://localhost:65532/MyWebsite/Page.aspx?PID=16483` which will give me the page I want it, everything looks good there but when I am trying to do the url rewrite with this rule:

```
 <rule name="Page View" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="actor/^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+)/?$" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="Page.aspx?N={R:1}&amp;PID={R:2}" />
                </rule>
```

And trying to open pages such as:

```
http://localhost:65532/MyWebsite/actor/bruce-willis/C-62
```

I am getting an error that the page cannot be found, how do you think I should tackle the rule in my case? Everything is set in both IIS and the page.
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Comment: Why to struggle with url-rewrite module if you can simply use URL routing? Any specific reason for that?

Comment: That's how the web app is done so far, I am taking over the source code from another dev. @walther